# Trying to delete GCE VM in Developer console fails

Tags: coreos

I have a VM (CoreOS stable) that I am attempting to delete via the developer console. It returns:

> Deleting instance  failed. Error: request failed with unknown
>   error.

Any idea what this means?

--p

Comment: Out of curiosity can you see if there is anything in the journal on the system (`journalctl --since="-3600"`)

Comment: This issue seemed to go away by itself after about an hour after I posted the query. I did not see the comment about the journal system until after the machine went away. Will check if it happens again.